# Java: Get X509Certificate Issuers

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

Hi i have this certificate(X509Certificate) but i need to get all the issuers of it, for example:

the certification path of the certificate is

```
-CA NATIONAL ROOT - Costa Rica 
 --CA NATURAL PERSON POLITICS - Costa Rica
   ---CA SINPE - NATURAL PERSON
      ----MARIO XXXXX XXXXXX (SIGN) --->
```

---> This is what i have, but i need to access the top issuer till reach the root(CA NATIONAL ROOT - Costa Rica), because i need to compare the name of the first issuer and other data, with some parameters. How do i accomplish this  or where should i start?

Comment: You have this certificate in what form? On disk? KeyStore? Part of an SSLSession?

Comment: You obviously need to have all those certificates, either already locally available, e.g. In the same keystore, or you need to be able to download them, e.g. From ldap sources. You should make sure, though, to somehow limit the possible sources to retrieve certificates from.  Otherwise you might too easily fall for fake certificate chains.

Answer (score -2):

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
//FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users//youtube//Documents//workspace//PublicKey02//archivo//archivo.p12");
//ks.load(fis, "passwordp12file".toCharArray());
ks.load(new FileInputStream("archivo//llave_criptografica.p12"), "su-password".toCharArray());
/*Enumeration<String> e = ks.aliases();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
   String param = e.nextElement();
   System.out.println(param);
}*/
//System.out.println(ks.containsAlias("myKey"));
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("2cba9e2d-6ec2-435e-b1bc-5fd9fe5afcac", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("su-password".toCharArray()));
```